# Error Message "invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned int’"

Tags: c++

I have this `unsigned int` function (it's a given function for the task)

```
// read data from virtual memory
unsigned int read(const int index) {
    return speicher[index];
}
```

In `speicher[index]` is a number, that I have to decode in 4 components. The first component is the value of `speicher[index] mod 16`, the second component is value of `(speicher[index])/(16*16)mod16` I think and so on.

other example with the error message. Maybe i can't understand what the function does:

for me the function `read(const int index)` should return an unsigned int number, that i can use like an "normal" other unsigned int number in the program.

```
unsigned int index = 0;
unsigned int test = 1;
do {
    unsigned int hexzahl = read(index);
    test = read(index);
    index = index + 1;
} while (index <= 255 && read(index) != 0);
// 37 actually i want, that the program breaks if the content of read(index) is 0
```

I can't understand the error message:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cpp:37: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
>
> main.cpp:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘char* (*)(const char*, int)’ to ‘int’
>
> main.cpp:37: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘unsigned int memory_read(int)’

Comment: Presumably `speicher` holds `void *`.

Comment: Please paste the error log with the line number and the exact code +/- 5 lines around the line that generates the error.

Comment: What is the type of `speicher`?

Comment: `unsigned int hexzahl = (cout << dec << read(index));` shouldn't compile.

Comment: `cout << dec << read(index)` this is very strange

Comment: what does that mean for my program?. Because there is a comment next to the read(const int index) function : "this function returns the value of address index". if it is of type void * how can i output the content of the memory-cell?

Comment: Please post a **complete error message** and don't paraphrase. `note: candidate is: std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::operator void*() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
       operator void*() const` is an important part of the error message.

Comment: ok i will do it again

Comment: In code you haven't posted, you call a function called memory_read with the name of a function, instead of a value, as its argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you expect this to do?

```
unsigned int hexzahl = (cout << dec << read(index));
```

This prints the value, then tries to assign the status of the `cout` stream to an integer. That makes no sense, which is why it won't compile.

If you want to set `hexzahl` to the result of `read`, then just do that:

```
unsigned int hexzahl = read(index);
```

and if you want to print the value then do that separately:

```
cout << dec << hexzahl;
```

If you want something other than the result of `read`, then please update the question to describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Still, I don't see any reason for the error to use `void *` instead of `ostream`.

Comment: @chris: Probably because (before C++11) there was an `operator void*` to allow `if (cout)` but disallow conversion to integer types. These days, there's an `explicit operator bool()` instead.

Comment: in memory[index] is a hex.number. I have to decode this number in 4 parts. So i wanted to output the content of memory[index] and then take the mod 16 of the number.

Comment: @Susliks: You'll have to output it in a separate statement. Do `cout << dec << hexzahl;` after initialising `hexzahl`.

Comment: i tried to write my answer better. Yes i see it, the part with cout << read(index) makes no sense, i`ve forgotten the number of speicher[index] is a dec.number. so i dont need the transformation from hex to dec... The compilation has work!, but the program isnt correct but this part i have to solve on my own... maybe i have to ask again later :

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I know about the conversion operator, but why would it use the conversion and then give a more cryptic error instead of just using the *original* type?

Comment: @chris I don't know or care exactly how a compiler might diagnose this. I was just describing what was wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the statement:

```
unsigned int hexzahl = (cout << dec << read(index));
```

The return type of `cout` is `void *`. You are trying to assign a `void *` to `unsigned int`, and that's why, you find the error.

The above statement is allowed in C `printf`, but not in C++ `cout`.

```
unsigned int hexzahl = (printf("%u%u", dec,read(index));  //In C language
```

`printf` returns the number of characters printed on the console which is an `unsigned int`. You may be trying the same in C++, which is impossible.

Comment: thank you! do you know how i can return the value of read(index). so that i can make a comparison betweek the value 0 and the value of read(index) ?

Comment: I can help you better if you post the whole program. Or at the least, the method named memory_read(int a);